# Top margin is subtracted from height in API10 and below

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In a project I'm working on, I'm positioning Views within a `FrameLayout` with `WRAP_CONTENT`:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0400">
        <TextView 
            android:background="#04FF00"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Since Android 3.0 (API11) the rendered layout is as expected:

[image: Expected result]

But in Android 2.3.3 (API10) and below, the `MarginBottom` of the green `TextView` seems to be extracted from the red `FrameLayout`:

[image: The wrong result]

Why is the layout not rendered as expected in API10 and below? Is this a bug in Android? If so, is there a quick workaround?

I know I could apply a bottom padding to the `FrameLayout` instead of a bottom margin to the `TextView`. But in my case I have no easy way to achieve this, since the layouts are built programmatically.

**Edit (22-07)**

During my quest to find out what fixed this issue, I looked at [the changes between API10 and API11](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes.html). But I can't find any chances in the `FrameLayout` class. This is weird because the following bug (which I think might be related) was fixed in API11: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28057.

**Edit (23-07)**

The margin bottom doesn't seem to be the problem; removing it doesn't make any difference. It seems to be the top margin which causes the wrong height in API10 and below.

Comment: try setting the text size(dp) in attributes. also make the padding zero

Comment: @Diljeet This doesn't make any difference

Comment: Probably a bug as in [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28057)

Comment: @Aprian This bug occurs when positioning a view (top left) with margins. A workaround for this bug is to add a gravity top to the views; as you can see I already did this in my example.

Comment: @sroes Why is that so? When built programmatically, you should have access to both the parent and childs, am i not right? If you have access to the parent, then what is the difficulty?

Comment: @Aprian I have a method which applies the positioning to the `LayoutParams`, so I don't have access to a `View`. I could change this method to also accept a `View`, but since my current solution already works in API11+, I was hoping for a quick workaround so I won't have to change much of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FrameLayout` documentation states the following:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other.

This was reason for me to drop the `FrameLayout`.

Then I started searching for a different `ViewGroup` which supports positioning elements by x / y and the ability to provide a gravity.

The `AbsoluteLayout` only supports positioning by x / y (and also is deprecated).

The `RelativeLayout` does extra measuring which (in my case) means bad performance.

So I ended up creating my own `ViewGroup`, which is basically a merge of the `FrameLayout`'s gravity, and the `AbsoluteLayout`'s x/y:

```
package com.example.common.widget;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FixedLayout extends ViewGroup
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_CHILD_GRAVITY = Gravity.TOP;

    private final ArrayList<View> mMatchParentChildren = new ArrayList<View>();

    public FixedLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FixedLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int count = getChildCount();

        final boolean measureMatchParentChildren =
                MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
                        || MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
        mMatchParentChildren.clear();

        int maxHeight = 0;
        int maxWidth = 0;
        int childState = 0;

        // Find rightmost and bottom-most child
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChildWithMargins(child, widthMeasureSpec, 0, heightMeasureSpec, 0);
                final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
                maxWidth =
                        Math.max(maxWidth, child.getMeasuredWidth() + lp.leftMargin
                                + lp.rightMargin);
                maxHeight =
                        Math.max(maxHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight() + lp.topMargin
                                + lp.bottomMargin);
                childState = childState | getChildMeasuredState(child);
                if (measureMatchParentChildren) {
                    if (lp.width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                            || lp.height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                        mMatchParentChildren.add(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Account for padding too
        maxWidth += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        maxHeight += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        // Check against minimum height and width
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, getSuggestedMinimumWidth());

        setMeasuredDimension(
                getResolvedSizeAndState(maxWidth, widthMeasureSpec, childState),
                getResolvedSizeAndState(maxHeight, heightMeasureSpec,
                        childState << MEASURED_HEIGHT_STATE_SHIFT));

        for (int i = 0; i < mMatchParentChildren.size(); i++) {
            final View child = mMatchParentChildren.get(i);

            final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthMeasureSpec;
            int childHeightMeasureSpec;

            if (lp.width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                childWidthMeasureSpec =
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft()
                                - getPaddingRight() - lp.leftMargin - lp.rightMargin - lp.x,
                                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
            else {
                childWidthMeasureSpec =
                        getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight()
                                + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin + lp.x, lp.width);
            }

            if (lp.height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
                childHeightMeasureSpec =
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingTop()
                                - getPaddingBottom() - lp.topMargin - lp.bottomMargin - lp.y,
                                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
            else {
                childHeightMeasureSpec =
                        getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom()
                                + lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin + lp.y, lp.height);
            }

            child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a set of layout parameters with a width of
     * {@link android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams#WRAP_CONTENT}, a height of
     * {@link android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams#WRAP_CONTENT} and with the coordinates (0, 0).
     */
    @Override
    protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams()
    {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Ask one of the children of this view to measure itself, taking into account both the
     * MeasureSpec requirements for this view and its padding and margins. The child must have
     * MarginLayoutParams The heavy lifting is done in getChildMeasureSpec.
     * 
     * @param child
     *            The child to measure
     * @param parentWidthMeasureSpec
     *            The width requirements for this view
     * @param widthUsed
     *            Extra space that has been used up by the parent horizontally (possibly by other
     *            children of the parent)
     * @param parentHeightMeasureSpec
     *            The height requirements for this view
     * @param heightUsed
     *            Extra space that has been used up by the parent vertically (possibly by other
     *            children of the parent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void measureChildWithMargins(View child, int parentWidthMeasureSpec, int widthUsed,
            int parentHeightMeasureSpec, int heightUsed)
    {
        final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();

        final int childWidthMeasureSpec =
                getChildMeasureSpec(parentWidthMeasureSpec, getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight()
                        + lp.leftMargin + lp.rightMargin + lp.x + widthUsed, lp.width);
        final int childHeightMeasureSpec =
                getChildMeasureSpec(parentHeightMeasureSpec, getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom()
                        + lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin + lp.y + heightUsed, lp.height);

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        int count = getChildCount();

        final int parentLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        final int parentRight = right - left - getPaddingRight();

        final int parentTop = getPaddingTop();
        final int parentBottom = bottom - top - getPaddingBottom();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();

                final int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                final int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();

                int childLeft;
                int childTop;

                int gravity = lp.gravity;
                if (gravity == -1) {
                    gravity = DEFAULT_CHILD_GRAVITY;
                }

                final int horizontalGravity = gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
                final int verticalGravity = gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;

                switch (horizontalGravity) {
                    case Gravity.LEFT:
                        childLeft = parentLeft + lp.x;
                        break;
                    case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:
                        childLeft = parentLeft + (parentRight - parentLeft - width) / 2 + lp.x;
                        break;
                    case Gravity.RIGHT:
                        childLeft = parentRight - width - lp.x;
                        break;
                    default:
                        childLeft = parentLeft + lp.x;
                }

                switch (verticalGravity) {
                    case Gravity.TOP:
                        childTop = parentTop + lp.y;
                        break;
                    case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                        childTop = parentTop + (parentBottom - parentTop - height) / 2 + lp.y;
                        break;
                    case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                        childTop = parentBottom - height - lp.y;
                        break;
                    default:
                        childTop = parentTop + lp.y;
                }

                child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + width, childTop + height);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        return new FixedLayout.LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
    }

    // Override to allow type-checking of LayoutParams.
    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p)
    {
        return p instanceof FixedLayout.LayoutParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p)
    {
        return new LayoutParams(p);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDelayChildPressedState()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Return only the state bits of {@link #getMeasuredWidthAndState()} and
     * {@link #getMeasuredHeightAndState()} of a child view, combined into one integer. The width
     * component is in the regular bits {@link #MEASURED_STATE_MASK} and the height component is at
     * the shifted bits {@link #MEASURED_HEIGHT_STATE_SHIFT}>>{@link #MEASURED_STATE_MASK}.
     */
    public final int getChildMeasuredState(View child)
    {
        return (child.getMeasuredWidth() & MEASURED_STATE_MASK)
                | ((child.getMeasuredHeight() >> MEASURED_HEIGHT_STATE_SHIFT) & (MEASURED_STATE_MASK >> MEASURED_HEIGHT_STATE_SHIFT));
    }

    /**
     * Utility to reconcile a desired size and state, with constraints imposed by a MeasureSpec.
     * Will take the desired size, unless a different size is imposed by the constraints. The
     * returned value is a compound integer, with the resolved size in the
     * {@link #MEASURED_SIZE_MASK} bits and optionally the bit {@link #MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL} set
     * if the resulting size is smaller than the size the view wants to be.
     * 
     * @param size
     *            How big the view wants to be
     * @param measureSpec
     *            Constraints imposed by the parent
     * @return Size information bit mask as defined by {@link #MEASURED_SIZE_MASK} and
     *         {@link #MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL}.
     */
    public static int getResolvedSizeAndState(int size, int measureSpec, int childMeasuredState)
    {
        int result = size;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
        switch (specMode) {
            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
                result = size;
                break;
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                if (specSize < size) {
                    result = specSize | MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL;
                }
                else {
                    result = size;
                }
                break;
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                result = specSize;
                break;
        }
        return result | (childMeasuredState & MEASURED_STATE_MASK);
    }

    /**
     * Per-child layout information associated with AbsoluteLayout. See
     * {@link android.R.styleable#AbsoluteLayout_Layout Absolute Layout Attributes} for a list of
     * all child view attributes that this class supports.
     */
    public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
    {
        /**
         * The horizontal, or X, location of the child within the view group.
         */
        public int x;

        /**
         * The vertical, or Y, location of the child within the view group.
         */
        public int y;

        /**
         * The gravity to apply with the View to which these layout parameters are associated.
         * 
         * @see android.view.Gravity
         */
        public int gravity = -1;

        /**
         * Creates a new set of layout parameters with the specified width, height and location.
         * 
         * @param width
         *            the width, either {@link #MATCH_PARENT}, {@link #WRAP_CONTENT} or a fixed size
         *            in pixels
         * @param height
         *            the height, either {@link #MATCH_PARENT}, {@link #WRAP_CONTENT} or a fixed
         *            size in pixels
         */
        public LayoutParams(int width, int height)
        {
            super(width, height);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new set of layout parameters with the specified width, height and location.
         * 
         * @param width
         *            the width, either {@link #MATCH_PARENT}, {@link #WRAP_CONTENT} or a fixed size
         *            in pixels
         * @param height
         *            the height, either {@link #MATCH_PARENT}, {@link #WRAP_CONTENT} or a fixed
         *            size in pixels
         * @param x
         *            the X location of the child
         * @param y
         *            the Y location of the child
         */
        public LayoutParams(int width, int height, int x, int y)
        {
            super(width, height);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new set of layout parameters. The values are extracted from the supplied
         * attributes set and context. The XML attributes mapped to this set of layout parameters
         * are:
         * 
         * <ul>
         * <li><code>layout_x</code>: the X location of the child</li>
         * <li><code>layout_y</code>: the Y location of the child</li>
         * <li>All the XML attributes from {@link android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams}</li>
         * </ul>
         * 
         * @param c
         *            the application environment
         * @param attrs
         *            the set of attributes from which to extract the layout parameters values
         */
        public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(c, attrs);
            TypedArray a =
                    c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                            com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout);
            gravity =
                    a.getInt(com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout_layout_gravity,
                            -1);
            x =
                    a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                            com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout_layout_x, 0);
            y =
                    a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                            com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout_layout_y, 0);
            topMargin =
                    a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                            com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout_layout_marginTop,
                            0);
            leftMargin =
                    a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                            com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout_layout_marginLeft,
                            0);
            bottomMargin =
                    a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                            com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout_layout_marginBottom,
                            0);
            rightMargin =
                    a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                            com.example.common.R.styleable.FixedLayout_Layout_layout_marginRight,
                            0);
            a.recycle();
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams source)
        {
            super(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:layout_gravity="top|left"` from your `TextView`

Add padding to parent layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF0400"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#04FF00"
        android:text="Test" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This is needed as a workaround for [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28057). Removing this means all the margins are ignored.

Comment: As for the padding on the FrameLayout: the layout is built programmatically, and there is no easy way for me to apply the bottom margin of the views to the bottom padding of the parent.